# mysql SHA1 password not reconizing php SHA1 password

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a problem calling up a user from the database because the SHA1 password is not comparing properly to the DB SHA1 password.

code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $username = $_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
if($username && $password) {


    $stmt = "SELECT memID, memFirst, memLast, roleID FROM MEMBER WHERE memEmail LIKE ? AND memPass = SHA1(?)";


    try{
        $STH = $DBH->prepare($stmt);
        $STH->bindParam(1, $username);
        $STH->bindParam(2, $password);
        $STH->execute();

        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo 'true';

        if($STH->rowCount() == 1) {
            echo 'count';
            $row = $STH->fetch();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['memID'];
            $_SESSION['user']['first'] = $row['memFirst'];
            $_SESSION['user']['last'] = $row['memLast'];
            $_SESSION['user']['role'] = $row['roleID'];
            $_SESSION['user']['timeout'] = time();

            header('Location: index.php');

        }

    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

}

}
```

the only record in the DB right now is a test user their record is:

```
|memFirst|memLast|roleID|memPass                         |memEmail     |
|test    |test   |3     |7110eda4d09e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac|test@test.com|
                         this is SHA1(1234)
```

these are the values that I'm calling but it won't bring the record up.

when I ran the code with the SHA1 DB value it runs perfectly, but when I try and run it based on the user's input it says the rowcount is 0.

Comment: *"but when I try and run it based on the user's input it says the rowcount is 0"* - So... does that POST array contain a value? check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: yes, it definitely has a value

Comment: Plus, if your connection uses the same variable for the password `$password`, then that will be a conflict, same for the username. I've seen that happen often before.

Comment: Then try `$password = SHA1($_POST['password']);` then `AND memPass = ?";`

Comment: my connection uses $dbpass. this is the only file that uses the variable $password

Comment: Then try $password = SHA1($_POST['password']); then AND memPass = ?" returns the same results

Comment: Is it possible you have same username.I mean to say username have user1,user1,have diffrent password 1234,12345 first one is false and second one also false if combination not match

Comment: Plus, using `WHERE memEmail LIKE ?` - If you have rows with emails that resemble themselves, your query will fail. So, you need to check for exactness, and not likeness. `WHERE memEmail = ?` and make sure you started the session and that no whitespace are being introduced. If so, `trim()`.

Comment: @TeamI Ok, sha1 is always 160  bits long and produces a 40 long string and your `7110eda4d09e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac` is only 32 long and has been cut off. so your column length isn't long enough and you need to increase it to accommodate the hash. So now, you have to clear that row, alter your column and create a new hash. Let me know if you want this as an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you that was my problem

Comment: @TeamI You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers!*

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sha1 is always 160 bits long and produces a 40 long string and your `7110eda4d09e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac` is only 32 long.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1

  Your column length isn't long enough and you need to increase its length in order to accommodate the hash.

  So now, you have to clear that row, alter your column and create a new hash.

As a sidenote:

If you later decide to use `password_hash()`, you have to keep in mind that it produces a 60-long string.

The manual for it suggests to use 255.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> *"Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."*